# Is there a way to display Excel results online using Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs, file-sharing

I have an Excel table that I'd like to be able to link to in a Facebook post.  It doesn't have to be the Excel file itself, it could be any kind of table as long as it has the necessary values, and a hyperlink that's publicly accessible.

I guess I'm thinking of something ideally where I could just copy/paste a block of cells into a data sheet.  I know that Google Docs does this, but is there a way to do it within that program so that all of my Facebook friends don't have to sign up for Google Docs if they don't want to?

Comment: I gave this an edit so that it's more in line with the scope (since we no longer accept web app requests).  Feel free to re-edit as necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I found out that you can do this with Google Docs, using File → Publish to the Web.